# Match IP without port 80

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match all IP addresses with port different than 80.

This regex almost works:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?!:80)
```

with this text:

```
94.79.78.146:44732
172.31.11.22:80
https://14.194.34.176:443/
"172.31.11.22:80"
```

It matches the IP addresses well, except for `172.31.11.22:80` where it matches `172.31.11.2`
notice how the last `2` is omitted.

How come? I have `[0-9]+` which is a greedy consumer, and it should match the entire number `22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole pattern has to match, and the reason it misses the last number, is because the `[0-9]+` can backtrack one step to so that the assertion `(?!:80)` is true.

You can prevent the backtracking by adding a word boundary `\b` after the last character class that matches numbers:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?!:80)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQ0Hrt/1)

If you do want to match for example port 8000 but not 80 you can add a word boundary after 80 as well.

As you are using `grep -Po` according to the comments, you can also use a possessive quantifier instead of a word boundary.

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]++(?!:80\b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase your regex as:

```regex
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:(?!80)[0-9]+
```

### Demo

This is slightly different than your version, and it asserts that the port is not 80, by placing the negative lookahead *after* the colon but before the `[0-9]+` for the port number.

Comment: Yeah that's what I got myself but I'm using `grep -Po` which gives me only the matches, I need the IPs without the port.

Comment: Your question and sample data strongly implied (at least to me) that you expected IP addresses with ports.